# Comparing a value with array values and finding the closest value?

Tags: java, android

When I press the button, I find the difference between the numbers selected in the spinners. And now the resulting result (float) needs to be compared with the array_alcohol array and select the closest value there. The step of increasing the array is 0.25. I don`t know how to get it. Code after chanches from Alexey. But the error is still there: tv_result.setText(array_alcohol[getClosestValueIndex(???)]);

```
btn_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            count();
        }
    });
}

public void count() {

    float num1 = Float.parseFloat(sp_dens.getSelectedItem().toString());
    float num2 = Float.parseFloat(sp_dens_sec.getSelectedItem().toString());
    float total = num1 - num2;
    Float[] array_alcohol = new Float[]{0f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1f, 1.25f, 1.5f, 1.75f, 2f, 2.25f, 2.5f, 2.75f, 3f, 3.25f, 3.5f, 3.75f, 4f, 4.25f,
    4.5f, 4.75f, 5f, 5.25f, 5.5f, 5.75f, 6f, 6.25f, 6.5f, 6.75f, 7f, 7.25f, 7.5f, 7.75f, 8f, 8.25f, 8.5f, 8.75f, 9f, 9.25f, 9.5f, 9.75f, 10f};
    tv_result.setText(array_alcohol[getClosestValueIndex()]);
}

public int getClosestValueIndex(Float[] array_alcohol, Float total) {
    int minIndex = 0;
    float lastDiff = Float.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < array_alcohol.length; i++) {
        float currentDiff = Math.abs(total - array_alcohol[i]);
        if (currentDiff < lastDiff) {
            lastDiff = currentDiff;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: The difference between two numbers is found by subtracting one from the other and taking the absolute value of the result.

Comment: I get changes, but it don`t work

Answer (score 0):

You should use compare values between a minimum value and maximum value. and use `&` operator to compare it.

```
btn_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            float num1 = Float.parseFloat(sp_dens.getSelectedItem().toString());
            float num2 = Float.parseFloat(sp_dens_sec.getSelectedItem().toString());
            float total = num1 - num2;

            for (int i = 0; i < array_alcohol.length; i++){

                float minValue = (float)(Float.parseFloat(array_alcohol[i]) - 0.25);
                float maxValue = (float)(Float.parseFloat(array_alcohol[i]) + 0.25);

                if (total > minValue  && total < maxValue) {

                    tv_result.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: if it worked don't forget to accept the answer so that other's can also take benefit from your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a regular way to find closest position in the array like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Float[] array = new Float[]{1.1f, -1.31f, 1.2f, 1.3f, 1.4f};
    Float test = 1.33f;
    System.out.println("Closest value is at position: " + getClosestValueIndex(array, test));
}

public static int getClosestValueIndex(Float[] array, Float test) {
    int minIndex = 0;
    Float lastDiff = Float.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        Float currentDiff = Math.abs(test - array[i]);
        if(currentDiff < lastDiff){
            lastDiff = currentDiff;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Closest value is: " + array[minIndex]);
    return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за ответ, но дело в том  что я в начале пути. Я начал заниматься 3 месяца назад. И я не совсем четко понимаю как адаптировать присланный вами пример к себе. Если б вы могли более подробно подсказать, я попытался бы усвоить.